# To start the gps while screen is locked

Tags: android, locking, screen, latitude-longitude

I've developed an application to get the latitude value using broadcast receiver. It's working fine, but whenever the screen is locked I don't get any value. But if I unlock the screen I get the value. Anybody kindly help for my issues?

Comment: is there a Crystall Ball for Android?

Comment: @mitch Wheat no crystall Ball

Comment: how you know you are not getting location values ? are you displaying location values any where ?

Comment: Try using `WakeLock`. And try using a `Service` instead of a `BroadcastReceiver`.

Answer (score 2):

When phone goes to deep sleep mode,  that is few minutes after the screen is switched off, The GPS stops.
 You need to acquire a WakeLock for the period you want to get GPS Updates

```
PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(context.POWER_SERVICE);
            wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "WakeLock");
            wakeLock.acquire();
```

and release the lock when you are done with it.

```
wakeLock.release();
```

See [Power Manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html)

Answer (score 1):

make sure you don't do anything strange in your **onPause** method, in my case I was mad because GPS stopped working when screen was locked, it was because in my onPause method I removed the updates from the location manager.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your manifest file it may help..i'm also not sure. Try once

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```